# Storing sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am creating an ASPwebsite, and I store my sessions like this way:

```
public List<User> getUser(string username, string password)
{
   SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @username AND Password = @password
}

List<User> userList = Database.getUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

foreach(User u in userList)
{
    Session["Username"] = u.Username;
}
```

Is this a good way of storing sessions? Can it be hacked or something like that with a cookie?

Or do you guys prefer me anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing your passwords in plain text?

Comment: Uhm, yes. For example when an users logs in and his username is Mike, then his Session will be Mike...

Comment: @xVizzi: That's not the password, that's the username.  But the code suggests that you're also storing the password in plain text.  It's unrelated to the question, but passwords should *never* be stored in plain text.  It's a *huge* security risk and is a really irresponsible thing to do to the users.  Passwords should be hashed before they're stored.  And then when a user logs in the password input should be hashed and compared with the hash in the database.

Comment: in this case, you are also assuming that it is possible for more than one user to have the same username and password. Why does this need to be a list ? when you foreach over it, the last entry in the list will be in the session, all the others will be overwritten. (not that it matters, because they'll all be the same anyway, but still)

Comment: @Thousand Nickname's are unique that's why I choose for list, do you recommend me another method?

Comment: if nicknames are unique, then it really doesn't make any sense to have the results come back in a list. You will never have more than 1 match if usernames are unique.

Comment: @David When an user registers I am hashing the password, but when someone logs in I am hashing it, I just made a simple getUser() method, because hashing wasn't my problem:P But thanks for the great tip though!

Comment: @xVizzi: I think the point he's making is that `getUser()` should return a single `User`, not a list of them.  If only one user can have any given username, it would only ever return one user.

Comment: @David But if I don't return a List, then I can't get the username and password with one method...

Comment: @xVizzi: Why can't you?  Both the username and password are on one `User` object.  So why can't you get them both from one `User` object?

Comment: @David Can I return two strings (Password and Username) with something like this: public string GetUsernamePassword() ?

Comment: @xVizzi: No, but you can with `public User getUser()`.  You said yourself that the function should only ever find one user, since usernames are unique.  So why does the function return a list of users if there's only ever one?

Comment: @David pff didn't know that was possible too -.- damn haha!

Comment: @David Going to try it with your method! But is the way of storing the sessions good?

Comment: @xVizzi: There isn't anything immediately wrong with it, but in time you may find better patterns for things.  It's enough to get you going and doesn't in and of itself present an immediate security risk.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to restrict your cookies only to Https portion of your website by setting the Cookies.Secure property to true. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.secure.aspx).

when this property is true, cookie may be sent only with https:// requests.

However ,still there's a lot to do and below few points may help you get a broader picture:

- Stealing session tokens via eavesdropping is much harder than say cross-site scripting (assuming there is a vulnerability). You need access to the network (e.g. user's LAN or ISP). Thus, according to risk-based prioritization developers should tackle XSS issues first because it provides a much bigger attack surface (the probability of an attack is much higher).
- If the business impact of sessions being hacked is high (e.g. storing credit cards for later use in a web shop), you might be better off restricting your whole site to HTTPS and then make cookies secure as explained earlier.

Some useful resources :

- [DigitalThreat](http://www.digitalthreat.net/2009/06/threat-vs-vulnerability-vs-risk/#)
- [Hacker'sHandbook](http://mdsec.net/wahh/)